# Making a Java EXE

Tags: java

I was following this tutorial: 
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html#tool

and I did everything exactly as they explained to make an EXE file from a Java project (not a JavaFX project), which is the first part of the tutorial. 
(the lower part is about JavaFX)

The EXE file is created, and I can install the application (by executing the EXE file).
But when trying to run, it says: "JavaFX Launcher Error: unable to invoke main method".

Any ideas?

I supose its recognizing the java file as an JavaFX project file, so its looking for the method **start()**, but I have no idea how I would solve this.

Comment: do you mean that you want your running jar to be .exe

Comment: Thats the idea. jar is too complex to execute, you have to use prompt code in most computers and get their natives on the same folder.

Comment: take a look at my answer

Comment: Javapackager used to be just for JavaFX but now is for any Java program.  Maybe these docs would help? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lots of stuffs which you can find for converting `.jar` to `.exe`
such as   **[launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)**,  **[exe4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/download/exe4j/files)**  etc.

Try **[exe4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/download/exe4j/files)** which is a common third party software for converting `.jar` to `.exe`

See the **[screenshots](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html)** of exe4j

Comment: I used exe4j and it worked normally... I am just getting this error log when executing: 

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
<log>
</log>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
<log>
</log>`

Answer (score 1):

`launch4j` is the best tool i can suggest to you. 
You can actually convert your `jar  to .exe`file.
And you can add some effects to the exe file too like adding splash screen like that.

Comment: I am using adicional _.jar_ libraries and external _dll_'s. How do I specify these options on launch4j? There is a **Classpath** tab, but I cannot edit the Classpath field that's inside it, only the 'Main class' and the 'Edit item' field.